# submit and return to same URL (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jsp

Need some help figuring out the simplest way to submit (only because I need to retrieve the selected value in a dropdown so I can use it in an other sql select in the same jsp) -

This is working (populates the drop down and triggers on change) -

```
<select name="assettypeid" id="assettypeid" onchange="typechanged();">                      
    <sql:query var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/database">
        SELECT id, name FROM assettype
    </sql:query>
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>    
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${queryresults.rows}">
        <option value="<c:out value="${row.id}"/>"
            <c:if test="${row.id == param.assettypeid}">
                <c:out value="selected"/>
            </c:if>
            <c:out value="${row.name}" />
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

This is working (extracts and confirms selected id) -

```
function typechanged() {       
    if(document.getElementById("assettypeid").selectedIndex == 0) {
        var typechosen = '%';
        alert(typechosen);
        return typechosen;
    }
    else {
        var typechosen = document.getElementById("assettypeid").value;
        alert(typechosen);
        return typechosen;
    }        
}
```

Now I want to submit so I can -

```
String typeselected = request.getParameter("assettypeid");
```

but I have no form or form name as such (I would rather not have to create one if this can be avoided because my overall page also has a refresh timer and the form seems to rerun the form submit each time the refresh occurs).

So, the javascript function should submit only once (when assetype changes) and returns me to the same URL / page without receiving warnings from browsers that I am refreshing on the same page.

Thoughts appreciated (I am a newbie so need as many notes as possible).

Regards
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript function , in which you can send the required values through ajax and call that function on `onchange` event.

```
  <script>
    function setValues() {

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                { 
                          // store the data retrieved

               document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
               }

                else {
                  alert(" Request not successful");
                }      

            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "url?assettypeid=" +  typechosen, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

    }
    </script>
```

Make `typechosen` a global variable

On the `onchange` event you call it like this:

```
<select name="assettypeid" id="assettypeid" onchange="typechanged();setValues();">
```

You can create a `div` on jsp as follows:

`<div id="demo></div>`

Don't forget to place the `div` before the `<script>` tag so that the function can get the `id`

Comment: Thanks ALearner, though my knowledge of ajax is non existent, I would need a lot of assistance and ideally a simple example

Comment: This should work for you . I have edited with a simle example

Comment: Much appreciated, tried but doesn't seem to be working. Wont typechosen be 'stuck' as a javascript variable and not accessible to the next sql select I need to run, or am I missing something?

Comment: You mean you want to make `typechosen` available as selectable values in the `<select>`?

Comment: No, once I have determined what typechosen is (when the dropdown is operated) I want to use typechosen in a separate sql select further down in the jsp. I think I have to do a submit in the function typechanged but presumably need a form (with post) to do this

Comment: Note that I have retried you code and am getting Request not successful, any further assistance appreciated.

Comment: The data retrieved from the server is not being stored anywhere store it in div like this(place this code in `if` statement) `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;`  and in jsp page place a div with id as `demo`  you can check if the value is retrieved and placed in the div

Comment: Thanks again but please be more specific as to how to do the div, store / recover the value etc (I am a newbie sadly), I don't have 'access' to the server and have to do everything in the same jsp.

Comment: I have added the required code to main  answer. The value of  `typechosen` should be displayed in the div. You can hide the `div` later if  you don't want the value to be displayed .

Comment: Thanks again, I will try this. As an aside please explain how "demo" becomes the value of typechosen. I think there will be issues because GET appends to the URL which will cause issues when my jsp refreshes automatically (the URL has a parameter) and POST will cause browser resend messages, but I will let you know.

Comment: You will get the `typechosen` value in the div when you send it back from the `server`. I did not add the url part because I don't know what framework you are using.

Comment: Thanks again, though I have no access to the server, I only have the one jsp (visualise.jsp) and that is already using a URL parameter when it reloads / refreshes. I did try the xmlhttp but it just hangs, seemingly when the send() occurs. My knowledge is limited as you can see.